# Dynamically loop over 2 columns in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have in a column a list of `email addresses` and another column with `keys` (unique ID), like this :
[image]

What I am trying to do is to send an email to each user with the `keys` in the email.
I manage to send emails, but for the same user like `toto@example`, it will send 5 emails with each the `key` corresponding.

However i'd like to group all the `keys` from the user, so something like concatanate the `keys` in the same string. As I call a function to send email like this : `Call sendEmail(object, email, body)`

I first tried to loop and compare each value with a Do while, but I completly lost in the loop:

```vb
    Sub sendEmailPart()

    Sheets(4).Activate
    Range("B1").Select
    Dim i, cpt As Integer
    Dim clefConcat As String
    i = 1
    cpt = 1
    clefConcat = ""
    Dim email, body, objectAs String
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        sujet = Range("A" & i).Value
        email = Range("B" & i).Value
        Do While email = ActiveCell.Value
            clefConcat = clefConcat & " " & Range("C" & cpt)
            cpt = cpt + 1
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
        i = i + 1
        contenu = clefConcat 
        Call sendEmail(object, email, body)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        
    Loop
End Sub
```

I want to learn from this, so, if possible, explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always find it easiest to use the `Scripting.Dictionary` object for such a thing.

Make a reference to that object in your references for the given VBA project.

[image: References]

... and then add this code to your module and run it.  You'll see it in a working example.

```
Public Sub SendEmailPart()
    Dim objDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim lngRow As Long, strEmail As String, strSubject As String, i As Long
    
    ' Change the sheet to the sheet object that matches your workbook.
    With Sheet1
        For lngRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            strEmail = .Cells(lngRow, 1)
            strSubject = .Cells(lngRow, 2)
        
            If strEmail = "" Then Exit For
        
            If Not objDict.Exists(strEmail) Then
                objDict.Add strEmail, strSubject
            Else
                objDict.Item(strEmail) = objDict.Item(strEmail) & ", " & strSubject
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    For i = 0 To objDict.Count - 1
        Debug.Print objDict.Keys(i) & " = " & objDict.Items(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

You should be able to adapt your project to that.

Comment: Your picture shows the wrong Library checked. You probably mean the "Scripting.Runtime", not the "Scriplet.Library".

Comment: @FunThomas ... killer pick up!  Thanks

Comment: @Skin  Can you explain a little more you code please ? I'm sorry but I'm new to use Dictionnary ^^

Comment: @LyessD https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object … it stores key/value pairs and therefore, you only need to loop through your dataset once to compile the email and subject values. If you run it, you’ll see it write out the concatenated subject lines for each email. I've updated my answer to output the email as well so you can see it more clearly. Just run the code anyway and you’ll see it working.

Comment: After reading docs and your infos, I was able to adapt this code to my needs. Thankx a lot for all this :)